# How to segregate a regression test suite area wise for CI-CD pipeline

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have developed a regression suite using Selenium Webdriver/TestNG/Maven. I have used data provider annotation and made it excel driven. The excel consists of 5-7 subject areas and the respective test cases are included inside the sheet. I enable the test case in any tab by giving Y in the indicator column. 
The problem I am facing here is that I want to integrate the suite in the pipeline. But I want to give the input which area or testcase I want to run and only that portion will run as part of the pipeline.

I tried using testng groups but its failing due to dataprovider.

Comment: Can you provide the code please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since your test cases are data driven and the decision to execute them or not is made via the column in your excel spreadsheet, you can do this easily by adding a filtering mechanism in your data provider method. Here's the set of steps and also a sample that elaborates the use-case.

1. Define a JVM argument using which you can obtain the category.
2. Have your data provider read the JVM argument value and based on the argument value filter out the data set and work with it.

Here's a sample that shows this in action.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassSample {

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void testMethod(String area, String category) {
    System.err.println("Area = " + area + ", Category = " + category);
  }

  @DataProvider(name = "dp")
  public Iterator<Object[]> getData(ITestContext ctx) {
    //Read the JVM argument. If no value is found we default to "all" categories.
    String categories = System.getProperty("category", "all");
    List<Object[]> data =
        new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(
                new Object[] {"Bangalore", "all"},
                new Object[] {"Chennai", "smoke"},
                new Object[] {"Mysore", "all"}));
    if (categories == null || categories.trim().isEmpty() || "all".equalsIgnoreCase(categories)) {
      return data.iterator();
    }
    data.removeIf(each -> !categories.equalsIgnoreCase(each[1].toString()));
    return data.iterator();
  }
}
```